# ASP.NET Custom Code Library Naming and Referencing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, webforms

I'm coding against two existing versions of an old library called say **Ab.Core** (old) and **AB.CORE** (new).

In VS 2010 I get the following error when trying to add a project reference for the older library (with the newer one already referenced):

> A reference to... Ab.Core could not be added. A reference to Ab.Core
>   already exists in the project.

It's looking like VS doesn't care about case sensitivity. I have to use both versions for a while - is there some way around this or some setting I can use?

Comment: Have a read on this http://kentb.blogspot.com.au/2008/11/visual-studio-referencing-same-assembly.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference two versions of assemblies that have the same fully-qualified type names,use an external assembly alias, the namespaces from each assembly can be wrapped inside root-level namespaces named by the alias, which enables them to be used in the same file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212(v=vs.100).aspx